# Xamarin forms Shell Navigation Android back button press

Tags: android, shell, xamarin, navigation, flyout

I noticed an insanely big bug with the Shell navigation. Am I doing something wrong?

Let's say we add 3 FlyoutItems to the Menu. After that navigate to the first one, then the second one, and finally the last one using the menu items.
Then press the back button of the mobile phone (I have Android 11). It will collapse the whole application to the background instead of navigating back to the second Page.
What do you think? That is a huge-huge UX bug In my opinion.

When I do the navigation with the await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(MyPage)) then the navigation stack is builded, so the back button will bring the previous page. But why not with menuitem navigation?

Comment: you are not navigating A -> B -> C, you are navigating Menu -> A, Menu -> B, Menu -> C.

Comment: Yes, I understand that, but I never seen any other application what handles the menu navigation like this. I think a random user don't expect that behavior from a mobile application. Can I change that for Menu-A-B-C?

Comment: For shell , it is designed like this.  What's the use of designing `shell`  if you want menu-A-B-C?